# Android Studio - Signed APK for release crashes

Tags: android-studio, crash, apk, release

I am creating a signed APK for the next update of my app. But when i transfer this APK file to my devices and install it, it crashes on opening the app.

Here is my project level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And here is my module gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.washkart.activities"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
compile(name:'acra-4.7.0', ext:'aar')
compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And i have added below lines in my proguard file to avoid the warning/error which i got durng signing the APK:

```
-keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.** {*;}
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v4.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *;}
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.jodatime.time.**
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
```

I have android studio 1.5.1 and testing on Android 4.4.2.
And the procedure which i used to generate in Build>Generate Signed APK>Selecting the module from dropdown > Add keystore file, alias and password> Build type = release > finish

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, the problem is in your proguard file.
you have enabled the proguard when used `minifyEnabled true`. 
Either disable it to disable to proguard or read about how to use proguard from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) as it discards the class files and other resource that are not added in proguard-rules.pro.